# Python - How to pull certain information out of a string?

Tags: python, file, loops

I'm working on a problem which consists of two programs. The first program will write a worker's ID, hourly pay rate, and hours worked to a text file four times. The second program will take the information entered from program #1's text file, display the worker's ID, and the worker's gross pay.

I've gotten the first program up and running, and the output is how it's supposed to be (the lab that this problem comes from gives you an example of how the output should look like)

Anyways, here's my code for the first program:

```
def main():
  output_file = open ('workers.txt', 'w')
  count = 0
  while count <= 3:
      id = input("Enter worker ID: ")
      rate = input("Enter hourly payrate: ")
      hours = input("Enter number of work hours: ")
      output_file.write(id + ' ')
      output_file.write(rate + ' ')
      output_file.write(hours + '\n')
      count = count + 1
  output_file.close()

  read_file = open ('workers.txt', 'r')
  empty_str = ''
  line = read_file.readline()
  while line != empty_str:
      print(line)
      line = read_file.readline()
  read_file.close()
main()
```

Now my question is - how would I write a second program in order to convert each line back into their respective variables, so that I can use the hourly pay & hours worked to calculate gross pay?

Comment: Consider making life a bit easier for yourself by adding a delimiter like a comma to separate the fields. This will make it easier to separate the values particularly if the fields contain a space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to break each line into a list, and unpack that list into variables:

```
with open('workers.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        worker_id, rate, hours = line.split()
        gross_pay = float(rate) * float(hours)
        print('ID: {}, gross pay: {:.2f}'.format(worker_id, gross_pay))
```

This assumes that the user will not enter any whitespace. It also assumes that the same worker id is not entered more than once.